# EPERM: operation not permitted, read

Tags: node.js, npm, file-permissions

I get this error when i try to install some packages
I tried to run cmd as admin, clean npm cache, reinstall node, but it is not working...

```
npm ERR! code EPERM
npm ERR! Error: EPERM: operation not permitted, read
npm ERR!     at C:\Users\caio\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\node_modules\gentle-fs\lib\rm.js:245:7
npm ERR!     at C:\Users\caio\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\node_modules\gentle-fs\node_modules\iferr\index.js:13:50
npm ERR!     at callback (C:\Users\caio\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\node_modules\graceful-fs\polyfills.js:295:20)
npm ERR!     at FSReqWrap.oncomplete (fs.js:154:5)
npm ERR!  { Error: EPERM: operation not permitted, read
npm ERR!     at C:\Users\caio\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\node_modules\gentle-fs\lib\rm.js:245:7
npm ERR!     at C:\Users\caio\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\node_modules\gentle-fs\node_modules\iferr\index.js:13:50
npm ERR!     at callback (C:\Users\caio\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\node_modules\graceful-fs\polyfills.js:295:20)
npm ERR!     at FSReqWrap.oncomplete (fs.js:154:5)
npm ERR!   cause:
npm ERR!    { Error: EPERM: operation not permitted, read
npm ERR!        at C:\Users\caio\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\node_modules\gentle-fs\lib\rm.js:245:7
npm ERR!        at C:\Users\caio\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\node_modules\gentle-fs\node_modules\iferr\index.js:13:50
npm ERR!        at callback (C:\Users\caio\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\node_modules\graceful-fs\polyfills.js:295:20)
npm ERR!        at FSReqWrap.oncomplete (fs.js:154:5)
npm ERR!      message: 'EPERM: operation not permitted, read',
npm ERR!      code: 'EPERM' },
npm ERR!   stack:
npm ERR!    'Error: EPERM: operation not permitted, read\n    at C:\\Users\\caio\\AppData\\Roaming\\npm\\node_modules\\npm\\node_modules\\gentle-fs\\lib\\rm.js:245:7\n    at C:\\Users\\caio\\AppData\\Roaming\\npm\\node_modules\\npm\\node_modules\\gentle-fs\\node_modules\\iferr\\index.js:13:50\n    at callback (C:\\Users\\caio\\AppData\\Roaming\\npm\\node_modules\\npm\\node_modules\\graceful-fs\\polyfills.js:295:20)\n    at FSReqWrap.oncomplete (fs.js:154:5)',
npm ERR!   code: 'EPERM' }
npm ERR!
npm ERR! The operation was rejected by your operating system.
npm ERR! It's possible that the file was already in use (by a text editor or antivirus),
npm ERR! or that you lack permissions to access it.
npm ERR!
npm ERR! If you believe this might be a permissions issue, please double-check the
npm ERR! permissions of the file and its containing directories, or try running
npm ERR! the command again as root/Administrator.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\caio\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2019-09-26T12_54_17_184Z-debug.log
```

Comment: file may be set to readonly. uncheck the readonly option in the file properties

Comment: What files? I tried to do this on the "C:\Users\caio\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\node_modules" folder, but it did not worked